# Parsing trouble! Bug in logic

Tags: java, parsing, arrays

I have a small bug here somewhere in my code! I must be blind because i really can't seem to find it or figure it out. I have a list of byte arrays. I'm parsing out the first 2 elements as well as the very last element in each array. If i get the value -16, -11 or -7 i want to keep the values. For some reason, the last value in on of the arrays is not being deleted. Why is this happening?

Comment: There's too much of your code missing from your example to be able to work out the problem easily.  For example, where does the variable "data" come from?  Perhaps that is even the source of your problem...?

Comment: woops... those are lists... i forgot to add that.. thanks for the heads up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried debugging it?

When you have `b = -110`
it passed this condition:

```
if(b!= -15 && i + 2 < srec.length() && (Character.digit(srec.charAt(i + 2), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(srec.charAt(i + 3), 16) != -15 
                && (Character.digit(srec.charAt(i + 2), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(srec.charAt(i + 3), 16) != -11)

b != 15 -> true
i + 2 = 124 < srec.length() = 142 -> true

(Character.digit(srec.charAt(i + 2), 16) << 4)+ Character.digit(srec.charAt(i + 3), 16) = -7 and -7 != -15 and also -7 != -11
```

hence the `data.add(b)` is executed.

Comment: i fixed the problem, you were definitely on the right track. so thansks :)